# What gets imported with UIKit, and how do I find out?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uikit

When using Objective-C and importing headers, it made sense to me what was getting imported. For example, I only have to import UIKit but I can use CoreGraphics, for example. How can I tell what other frameworks each framework is importing with Swift? All I'm doing is importing UIKit, but I can still use Core Graphics. I've searched the documentation, but the framework reference doesn't mention it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Open your Swift source file. Find the `import UIKit` line. Command-click on the word `UIKit`. You'll see what `UIKit` imports:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit.NSAttributedString
import UIKit.NSFileProviderExtension
import UIKit.NSLayoutConstraint
import UIKit.NSLayoutManager
import UIKit.NSParagraphStyle
import UIKit.NSShadow
import UIKit.NSStringDrawing
import UIKit.NSText
import UIKit.NSTextAttachment
import UIKit.NSTextContainer
... many more
```

Command-click on the word `Foundation` on the first line to see what it imports:

```
import CoreFoundation
import CoreGraphics
import Foundation.FoundationErrors
import Foundation.NSArray
import Foundation.NSAttributedString
import Foundation.NSAutoreleasePool
import Foundation.NSBundle
import Foundation.NSByteCountFormatter
import Foundation.NSByteOrder
... many more
```

Repeat until bored or satisfied.

Comment: Oh my gosh this is amazing. Is there anyway to access this through other means (like the way you could navigate to the objc header files in the file browser)? And I guess my main question is, where can I learn more about Swift modules? I've been searching the documentation and reading the iBook but it's still a mystery.

Comment: Swift documentation from Apple is pretty sparse right now. What you can find by command-clicking things in Xcode is pretty much all there is.

Comment: Note that just because FrameworkA import FrameworkB (for example `SwiftUI` imports `Combine`), you might not have access to it automatically. I was confused and asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67353167/14351818) here, if anyone else is interested.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the [documentation on Swift](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html).

[image]