# Why do I need to import Combine when SwiftUI already imports it?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, combine

I'm trying to listen to `@State` changes and followed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64659265/14351818). Here's my code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var isOn = false
    
    var body: some View {
        Toggle("Selection", isOn: $isOn)
            .onReceive(Just(isOn)) { isOn in
                print("Toggle is on? \(isOn)")
            }
    }
}
```

It doesn't compile: I get "Cannot find 'Just' in scope"

[image: Cannot find 'Just' in scope with the line containing 'Just' highlighted]

[`Just` is part of the Combine framework](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/just). But, I thought SwiftUI already imported Combine? I <kbd>Command</kbd>-clicked `import SwiftUI`, then pressed `Jump to Definition`, and there it was at the top.

| Jump to Definition | `import Combine` is at the top |
| --- | --- |
| [image: Jump to Definition in popup menu] | [image: Line 1 of SwiftUI file is import Combine] |

Once I add `import Combine` to my code, it compiles. But shouldn't this be redundant and unnecessary?

[image: Build succeeded]

Comment: It pulls in the namespace, try `Combine.Just(isOn)` without `import Combine`

Comment: Modules are not a objective-c/c headers - import is visible only in place actually where import is.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just because you import from a certain framework/library (module A) does not automatically mean you get access to all of the types that module A imports (module B, C, D) in your file where you've imported *just* `A`.

A perfect example of that is what you are experiencing, where `SwiftUI` imports `Combine`, but you can't use `Just` in your code without explicitly importing `Combine` yourself.

However, this isn't true *all* of the time. For example, `CGFloat` is defined in `CoreGraphics`, but you have access to it if you import `SwiftUI`. You *don't* have access to it, if you only import `Foundation`. Of course, this is not a perfect example since your question references two Swift frameworks, while CoreGraphics and Foundation come from the Objective-C world.

In order for you to *not* have to import `Combine`, the SwiftUI framework would have to export Combine for you. This can be done using `@_export`:

- https://forums.swift.org/t/exported-and-fixing-import-visibility/9415/3
- https://thoughtbot.com/blog/swift-imports
- [What is the "@exported" attribute in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33558995/what-is-the-exported-attribute-in-swift)

Since that has not been done, you're stuck importing `Combine` when you want to use its types, just as you have to import `CoreData` if you want to use `CoreData` types, even though, like `Combine`, it is *imported* (but not exported) by SwiftUI.